# Jquery function for retrieving input values of the active checkbox when the page loads. JFIDDLE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to display the values of the selected checkbox when the page loads. Currently, the values are displayed when I click on a checkbox, but I need the values from the default checkbox when page loads.

Here if the link to my code: [JFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vj0hmbso/)

Here is a link to my page: [My Website](https://www.aarontomlinson.com/shop_pages/mmd/products/amnesia.php)

Here is my code copy & paste:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TEST LIST</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="simpleCart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset id="" class="" style="margin-top: 0px;font-variant: small-caps;letter-spacing: 2px;" data-role="controlgroup">

    <input class="weight1" type="hidden" value="2.0" >
    <input class="price1" type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2a" value="20.00" checked="checked">
    <label class="price_weight_lable1" style="display: flex;" for="radio-choice-v-2a">
        <div style="flex:2;">2.0 grams</div>
        <div style="flex:1;text-align: center;">$22.00</div>
    </label>


    <input class="weight2" type="hidden" value="3.5" >
    <input class="price2" type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2b" value="45.00">
    <label class="price_weight_lable2" style="display: flex;" for="radio-choice-v-2b">
        <div style="flex:2;">3.5 grams</div>
        <div style="flex:1;text-align: center;">$45.00</div>
    </label>


   <input class="weight3" type="hidden" value="7.0" >
    <input class="price3" type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2c" value="90.00">
    <label class="price_weight_lable3" style="display: flex;" for="radio-choice-v-2c">
        <div style="flex:2;">7.0 grams</div>
        <div style="flex:1;text-align: center;">$90.00</div>
  </label>  
</fieldset>

    <script>

$('input[type=radio]').on( 'change', function(el){
  $( '.weight_results' ).text( $(this).parent().prev().val() );
  $( '.price_results' ).text( $(this).val() );
});
    </script>




<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">


    <div class="item_price"> <!-- simplecart div -->    
        <div class="price_results"></div> <!-- price function result? -->                          
    </div>

     <div class="item_weight"> <!-- simplecart div -->   
        <div class="weight_results"></div>   <!-- weight function result? -->                        
    </div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ use the document ready function. Put this in your head and any JS you want to happen after the DOM is loaded in there. $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/vj0hmbso/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in my above comment here is an example. Just put this in your  and then run the desired JS.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert($("#myInput").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="myInput" type="text" value="SOME TEXT HERE">
```

Comment: $( document ).ready(function() {
 
 $( '.price_results' ).text($(".price1").val() );
   $( '.weight_results' ).text($(".weight1").val() );
 
});

Answer (score 0):

Simply Add `.change()` at the last of your code to make the `change` event run on page load

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=radio]').on( 'change', function(el){
    $( '.weight_results' ).text( $(this).parent().prev().val() );
    $( '.price_results' ).text( $(this).val() );
  }).change(); // add .change to run the code on load
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

<fieldset id="" class="" style="margin-top: 0px;font-variant: small-caps;letter-spacing: 2px;" data-role="controlgroup">

    <input class="weight1" type="hidden" value="2.0" >
    <input class="price1" type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2a" value="20.00" checked="checked">
    <label class="price_weight_lable1" style="display: flex;" for="radio-choice-v-2a">
     <div style="flex:2;">2.0 grams</div>
     <div style="flex:1;text-align: center;">$20.00</div>
    </label>
 

    <input class="weight2" type="hidden" value="3.5" >
    <input class="price2" type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2b" value="45.00">
 <label class="price_weight_lable2" style="display: flex;" for="radio-choice-v-2b">
  <div style="flex:2;">3.5 grams</div>
     <div style="flex:1;text-align: center;">$45.00</div>
 </label>

  
   <input class="weight3" type="hidden" value="7.0" >
    <input class="price3" type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2c" value="90.00">
    <label class="price_weight_lable3" style="display: flex;" for="radio-choice-v-2c">
  <div style="flex:2;">7.0 grams</div>
     <div style="flex:1;text-align: center;">$90.00</div>
  </label>  
</fieldset>



 <div class="item_price"> <!-- simplecart div -->    
  <div class="price_results"></div> <!-- price function result? -->                          
 </div>
 
  <div class="item_weight"> <!-- simplecart div -->   
  <div class="weight_results"></div>   <!-- weight function result? -->                        
 </div>
```

> Note: wrap code on `$(document).ready()` as
>   [Icewine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3492285/icewine) said